# How to add a search path for packages in TexStudio on Mac OS?

Tags: packages, texstudio, mac, paths, texinputs

I would like to add a custom folder into the search path of TexStudio on OS X Yosemite for using custom packages. Is it possible to do so in a way that it would work when compiling LaTeX documents from GUI?

I think it might be possible to do so by changing **$TEXINPUTS** environment variable, but I do not know how to manage this approach.

- Do I have to change this variable every time before running TexStudio?
- If yes, is it possible to append corresponding command to one of the execution commands in the configurations of TexStudio?

Comment: Does this one help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: @Johannes_B It works as a temporary solution. 
However my ultimate goal is to be able to add an arbitrary folder in a search path, not only subfolders of TeX home directory

Comment: Well, that would have been the natural LaTeX solution. You can use `$TEXINPUTS`  and similar. [Setting environment variables in OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688)